# IconButton works on secound click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

It's driving me nut's. onClick handler is firing on secound click. I dont know why. The functional component is so simple that should work. This component is a part of another comp. so it's a child. Parent comp is on the list. That is whole setup. If I click first time I saw on the debug that it's not's going fire the event. Style span of IconButton are changing in first click. Strange

```
const MoreInfo = () => {
  const [more_info, setMore_info] = useState("test");
  const handleExpand = event => {
    if (icon_expand === "expand_more") {
      setMore_info("test2");
    }
  };

  return (
    <IconButton onClick={handleExpand} aria-label="location" size="small">
      <Icon style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{icon_expand} </Icon>
    </IconButton>
  );
};
export default MoreInfo;
```

Comment: what is icon_expand? where is it coming from?

Comment: It's a state variable but it's dosent mater because on first click it's not fireing the CLIK handleExpand and I dont know why. It's workink on secound click ("debug catch and go into function"). I even rewrite function component to class and the result are still the same. Is there any limitation on how buttons are handled comoponent in a component?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it does work as you expected.

I just copy pasted your code in codesandbox and it does work  [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dan-d5r8r).

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dan-d5r8r

However, as you mentioned the whole tree of components and it's child component of any parent component.

**So I guess and you should check some of this**:

- check onClick of parent and make sure it's not  conflicting with any other onClick ( name ).
- make sure state updation works properly
- check all methods are binded ( only if applicable )

Comment: It's strange because it's happend when i put the code inside a component outside in the parent works fine